# Guidance needed for leave Report logic and functions in python

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, tornado, peewee

I am working in python 2.7, tornado web service, peewee  for database.

Scenario To get leave report for each month 26 to next month 25.

So I did this below sample scenario(but logically i am stuck it out)

I am getting **from_date**,**to_date** from UI(selecting report for 26-04-2016 to 25-05-2016)

**Leavetable** is a table name (it has Employee id, leave from date, leave to date, working_days)

**working_days** is nothing but count of each leave(29-04-2016 - 02-05-2016) = 2 (saturday and sunday excluded already)

For a single employee total leave in particular month
sample leaves are

- 24-04-16 - 26-04-16,
- 28-04-16 - 29-04-16 ,
- 15-05-2016 to 29-05-2016

My code (Help me to change)

```
       value=0
       for report in Leavetable.select().where(Leavetable.Employee_ID==employees_id):
            db_from_date = report.From_Date
            if (from_date<=db_from_date and to_date>=db_from_date):
                workingday=float(report.Working_Days)+value
                value= workingday
                print value
```

It getting in value = 3 for the same leave above of

- 24-04-16 - 26-04-16(it is have to take 1day but not working out by
  this code)
- 28-04-16 - 29-04-16(it is taken (2 days)
- 15-05-2016 to 29-05-2016( 26,27,28,29 have to exclude this 4 days)

Guide me what is the simplest solution to get this logic work out please do the needful.

As per solarflare guidance I added the below code.

But even logically its not fit.The above scenario leave of 15-05-2016 to 29-05-2016 This leave also counting when i am taking report of 15-04-2016 to 15-05-2016

```
        value=0
        for report in Leavetable.select().where(Leavetable.Employee_ID==employees_id):
            for dt in rrule(DAILY, dtstart=report.From_Date,until=report.To_Date):
                if (dt.weekday() < 5):
                    if (report.To_Date>=from_date and report.From_Date<=to_date):
                        value += 1 
                    print value
```

Comment: It took me a while to understand what you are asking. Please always write down exactly what you are expecting as a result and what you are getting as a result (and use correct table columns). To your question: You have two errors: 1. you cannot use the field `Working_days` because it is always for the entire period, you have to calculate for each day that is in your period if it is a workday and in between from_date and to_date. 2. in your `if...` you can only exclude periods that ended before from_date and started after to_date; now, you would miss the 4 days of 3rd period next month.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: @Solarflare yes you are r8 that was the issue without working days it will took long process so i used that If you have any solutions or idea?

Comment: Every computer that was build after 1940 should be able to add 20 numbers instead of 3 in a reasonable amount of time. You just have to do a loop from `report.From_Date` to `report.To_Date` and check if a) `loopvariableoftypedatetime.weekday()` is < 5 (Monday will be 0, Friday 4) and b) if it is inside the boundarys. You should select just reports that have `report.To_Date >= from_date` and `report.From_Date <= to_Date` directly in the query or in the `if`. This is, as you wanted, the guide to the simplest solution. Try that, post your code and we can fix it if you still have problems.

Comment: @Solarflare Thanks for your valuable effort I clearly understood your solution b but a)you said "You just have to do a loop from report.From_Date to report.To_Date" .I am not clear on this loop, what kind of loop i have to do . if possible can you add the loop in above code based on the scenario. Edit and post as a answer.

Comment: @soarflare if i add your condition, please check above scenerio leave of 15-05-2016 to 29-05-2016 it is also included.when i am taking report of same 26-04-2016 to 25-05-2016.

Comment: You can loop through all the dates e.g. by `for dt in rrule(DAILY, dtstart=report.From_Date, until=report.To_Date): if (dt.weekday() < 5 and...(check for boundarys as describes in b) )...) ... value += 1 `. You need to import `from dateutil.rrule import rrule, DAILY` and of course `from datetime import date`. You should now have every piece of code you need. It is 5 lines of code without the imports (6 for an additional `if` if you dont change your `where`, 7 including `print value`). If you still have problems, post your code and the (wrong) result and any error messages.

Comment: @solarflare please the above code which I added at last of my question.

Comment: I guess it would have been so much faster if I just had wrote you the code :-/ But we are getting close now. Your `if (report.To_Date...` belongs to the 3rd line (before `for dt in ...`). And you still didn't add the `if (dt.weekday() < 5 and...(check for boundarys as describes in b) )...)` part. Hint: it looks something like `if ((dt.weekday() < 5) and (from_date <= dt <= to_date)):`.

Comment: Thanks solarflare i am little bit confused on this dt . can you please edit the above code like which you think .

Comment: `dt` is the variable in the `for`-loop. Did you actually try the code? "looks like" was a joke. It is the complete code. Just copy and paste it.

Comment: @Solarflare I understood already dt is a variable. but my confusion is on this comment code. Is there any problem on editing my above code or post an answer. If no please post an answer or edit the above code in my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Altered the above code with basic if logic and the above scenario got satisfied The code I listed below may be some variable name may difficult to understand if any comment here:

```
                    if (db_from_date>= prev_month and db_to_date<=this_month):
                        counting = float(working_day)
                        leave_availed=value+counting
                        value=leave_availed

                    elif(db_from_date >= prev_month and db_from_date <= this_month and db_to_date > this_month):
                        counting = float(working_day)
                        check_point =counting + 0.5
                        extra_days = workdays.networkdays(this_month_date,db_to_date,holidays)
                        if int(check_point)==check_point:
                            extra_days=extra_days - 0.5
                        count=counting-extra_days
                        leave_availed=value+count
                        value=leave_availed

                    elif(db_from_date < prev_month and db_to_date>=prev_month and db_to_date <= this_month):
                        counting = float(working_day)
                        extra_days = workdays.networkdays(db_from_date,prev_month_date,holidays)
                        count = counting - extra_days
                        leave_availed=value+count
                        value=leave_availed

                    elif(db_from_date < prev_month and db_to_date > this_month):
                        count = workdays.networkdays(prev_month,this_month,holidays)
                        leave_availed=value+count
                        value=leave_availed

                    else:
                        leave_availed=0
```